# Can't stop node server testing with superagent

Tags: node.js, express, supertest

There are many questions related to this, but I couldn't find any response useful because it applies to a very particular case.

I'm wrapping express in a module, and starting and closing connection like this:

```
var server = express(),
    runningInstance = {};

server._listen = server.listen;
server.listen = server.init;

// Start it up!
server.init = function(callback) {
  configure();

  runningInstance = server._listen(config.PORT, config.HOST, function() {
    logger.OK('Express server listening at %s:%d', config.HOST, config.PORT);
    if(callback && typeof callback == 'function') { return callback(); }
  });
};

server.close = function(callback) {
  if(!runningInstance.close) {
    if(callback && typeof callback == 'function') { return callback('Tried to close a server that\'s not up'); }
    else { return; }
  }

  // Once the server closes, log it and rock the callback
  if(callback && typeof callback == 'function') runningInstance.once('close', function() {
    logger.OK('Express server closed at %s:%d', config.HOST, config.PORT);
    callback();
  });

  // Stops the server from accepting new connections
  runningInstance.close(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      logger.error('Tried to close a server that\'s not up on %s:%s', config.HOST, config.PORT);
      if(callback && typeof callback == 'function') { return callback(err); }
      else { return; }
    }
  });
};
```

Now, my tests:

```
it('Creating the server should not fail', function(done) {
  server.init(function(err) {
    expect(err).to.not.exist;
    done();
  });
});

it('Should close the server', function(done) {
  server.once('close', function() {
    request(server)
    .get('/')
    .expect(404, done);
    done();
  });
```

I'm expecting the server to give me a 404 after closing, but It's actually responding with a 200.

I don't really know why is this happening, the on('close') callback is being executed, and the server doesn't start again before the request...